# Flux architecture - how to know in controller when async event from action is completed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactjs-flux, flux

I'm learning `flux` architecture. I'm trying to add new user. When user clicks `save` button on UI, in my controller I call an action creator's `createUser` function to initiate async request:

```
    addNewUser: function () {
        HdfsUsersActions.createUser($scope.newUser);
    }
```

Action creator function:

```
    createUser: function (user) {
        return restService.createHdfsUser(user).then(function (data) {
            flux.dispatch('platform-manager-ADD_USER', data);
        });
    }
```

Then I need to know when async request is over and its status to hide user add UI form in html. What's the correct approach here?

I can do it like this:

```
HdfsUsersActions.createUser($scope.newUser).then(function() {
   //hide user add form on UI
});
```

But this doesn't seem to be the right approach because it seems that under the `flux` architecture the only way a controller gets data is from a `store`. Here, using `then` seems to break that rule as the data comes from an `action creator`

Comment: since the question is not about any particular framework, but rather about architecture paradigm of flux

Comment: "But this doesn't seem to be the right approach."... if you call a function that returns a promise, then this is indeed the right approach until `async/await` lands. What makes you think this is incorrect?

Comment: @spender, because it seems that under the `flux` architecture the only way a controller gets data is from a `store`. Here, using `then` seems to break that rule as the data comes from an `action creator`

Comment: please update the main question(How to know from controller when async event is completed), as i very much doubt that is what you are wanting to know. you are more likely wanting to know . In javascript angularjs how do you know went a quest is complete. This has nothing to do with async vs not async. its got to do with how to handle responses from angularjs and when they are complete.

Comment: @Maximus sorry I really!!! am not! trying to be an $ss, but it is still a miss leading title. "Flux architecture - how to know from controller when async event from action is completed" should be something like "Flux architecture - How to know when the request is finished/done."
Could also possible be "Angularjs - How to know when the request is finished/done." but I would need to google flux to ensure hence I'm not changing the title myself. but I understand enough to know the current terminology doesn't accurate represent what you want to know.

Comment: @Seabizkit, thanks for your comment, but I think the title now is OK)

Answer (score 0):

When you receive answer from async call, you will dispatch event `platform-manager-ADD_USER`:

```
flux.dispatch('platform-manager-ADD_USER', data);
```

Then, you should listen to this event in store, and update itself with received `data`. Then all components which listen to this change will receive updates and rerender themselves if it's needed.